# Build lookup table from multiple input attributes

Tags: fme-form

In FME, how could I build a lookup table with multiple input attributes, such as the one presented here: https://community.safe.com/s/article/advanced-schema-mapping-schemamapper which looks like:

[image: sample lookup table in FME]

and which comes from an input table defined by these fields:

`MaterialTypeAttribute`: The name of an attribute which defines the pipe material.
`MaterialTypeValue`: Potential values of pipe material.
`DiameterAttribute`: The name of an attribute which defines the pipe diameter.
`DiameterValue`: Potential values of pipe diameter.
`StatusAttribute`: The name of an attribute which defines the pipe status.
`StatusValue`: Potential values of pipe status.

?

Comment: Conditional Values can be used in the Attribute Manager to set rules https://community.safe.com/s/article/determining-attribute-values-by-testing-with-condi

Comment: Indeed, but when there are more than 600 different conditional on several columns, you probably want to automate this a little... I guess.

Answer (score 1):

Use a Sampler, set on 1st N features, group by MaterialTypeAttribute, MaterialTypeValue, DiameterAttribute, DiameterValue, StatusAttribute, StatusValue. Then split to 2 AttributeCreators creating the autocad_color and autocad_lineweight attributes. Bring them together and you're done. Write out to Excel or CSV and add the values you want.

[image: workflow]

[image: result]